# In Perl, why does concatenating a hash with a string give a fraction-looking result?

Tags: string, perl, concatenation, perl-data-structures

I have the following hash:

```perl
my %villains = {
    "Boba" => "Fett",
    "Darth" => "Vader",
    "Moff" => "Tarkin",
}
```

I then print it like so:

```
print "".%villains;
```

I get the following output:

```
1/8
```

What semantics in Perl make this happen?

Thank you!

Comment: Note that you've assigned one key here with a reference and no value. Putting the hash contents in curly braces (`{` and `}`) assigned a _hash reference_, not a hash. You declare a hash and feed it a _hash reference_. So you'll never get more than one bucket filled.

Comment: This is a very good first question. Well done!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are evaluating the hash in scalar context. When you do this it actually returns a fraction of the number of buckets touched over the total number of buckets, unless the hash has not been used in which case it evaluates to false.  See [this perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-values) for more info (near the end of the section).

Answer (score 4):

> [If you evaluate a hash in scalar context, it returns false if the hash is empty. If there are any key/value pairs, it returns true; more precisely, the value returned is a string consisting of the number of used buckets and the number of allocated buckets, separated by a slash. This is pretty much useful only to find out whether Perl's internal hashing algorithm is performing poorly on your data set.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-values)

This could use some explaining for anyone unfamiliar with hash internals: When items are added to a hash, they're arranged into buckets based on a hashing algorithm so they can be retrieved more efficiently.

## Example

You're collecting toy cars. In order to find your cars easily you've decided to put them in different buckets based on colour. You have buckets for **Red**, **Yellow**, **Green**, **Blue** and **Black** coloured cars.

You add a new **Green** Ford Mustang to your collection so it goes in the **Green** bucket. Next time you want to find this car, you can go directly to the **Green** bucket and have a smaller selection to search through.

In this example the car collection is a `hash`, each car is a `hash entry` and colour is the `hashing algorithm`. As the collection also contains red, blue and black cars they are arranged fairly efficiently, using `4/5` of the buckets.

However, if you were to use this system for a collection of red cars, the hashing algorithm would be very inefficient. It would only use `1/5` of the buckets and finding a particular car would involve searching through the entire collection.